# How to send values from Django views function to Django forms class during runtime?

Tags: python, django

My Django Template:

```html
{% extends 'main/base.html' %}
{%block title%}Delete List{%endblock%}

{%block content%}
    <form method="post" action="/delete/">
        {%csrf_token%}
        {{form}}
        <button type="sumbit" name="Delete List">Delete List</button>
    </form>
{%endblock%}
```

my function inside view:

```py
def delete(response):
    if response.method=="POST":
        form1 = DeleteList(response.POST)
        print(f"delete button pressed: {form1.is_valid()}")#just checking
        if form1.is_valid():
            ""
            print("valid form: {}".format(form1.cleaned_data))#just checking
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/display")
    else:
        #form1 = DeleteList(10) -- iam trying to make this style work...and use a integer value from my database to set maxVaue of a field
        #Example: form1 = DeleteList(name="test",data2="somedata"...) -- i want this style to work cause I would pass more values to my forms class in future 
        form1 = DeleteList()
    return render(response,"main/deleteList.html",{"form":form1})
```

my django forms class:

```py
class DeleteList(forms.Form):
    #i was trying to make this __init__ work but seems to be buggy
    """def __init__(self,maxValue:int, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DeleteList, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['id'] = forms.IntegerField(label="Enter id",min_value=1,max_value=maxValue)
    id = forms.IntegerField()"""    
    
    #below one is just static, iam trying to replace this with the above commented block of code
    id=forms.IntegerField(label="Enter id",min_value=1,max_value=10) #-- only this seems to work
```

Now if do `form1 = DeleteList(<int value here>)`  and receive it on `__init__` of forms class, I am able to get the values into form and set my `IntegerField's max_value`,
it only seems to work when the form loads the first time, then when the form is submitted and while receiving the post data on my views function(DeleteList): `form1.is_valid()` is always false.

So how do i set my forms `IntegerField's max_value` from my django views function and still be able to receive my post method data back to the same view function and have `form1.is_valid()` return ture to continue with the form flow?

EDIT:
and this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.initial does not help either, this does not seems to work for properties of the elements like `IntegerField's max_value`

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the value down as a `kwarg` and remove it before sending down to Form Base class. Follow the example:

```
class DeleteList(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        caller = kwargs.pop('maxValue')
        # YOUR DESIRED LOGIC
        super(DeleteList, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: It would work great if it were just a normal class , but since its django forms class, we will get error of this sort : "BaseForm.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'maxValue'"

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution, I just added my `integer-i-want-to-use` to the post method too and it all works fine

my django forms class is:

```
class DeleteList(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self,maxValue:int, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DeleteList, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['id'] = forms.IntegerField(label="Enter id",min_value=1,max_value=maxValue)
    id = forms.IntegerField()
```

my Django views function:

```
def delete(response):
    if response.method=="POST":
        form1 = DeleteList(10,response.POST)#early this was just form1 = DeleteList(response.POST)
        print(f"delete button pressed: {form1.is_valid()}")#just checking
        if form1.is_valid():
            ""
            print("valid form: {}".format(form1.cleaned_data))#just checking
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/display")
    else:
        form1 = DeleteList(10)
    return render(response,"main/deleteList.html",{"form":form1})
```

so in POST doing this `form1 = DeleteList(10,response.POST)` seems to solve this problem for me

is this the best way to send data from view function to forms class?

from what i can read in the documentation , it points to this : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.initial  , but this does not seem to work for changing `IntegerField's max_value`
and it works for changing `<any fields>'s value`

it would be great If anyone can clarify on why Form.initial(mentioned on the documentation link) is not working for my case and is the method I am using the only way to set `IntegerField's max_value` ?

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/31890734)

Comment: @ray ray this is the answer... i have a working solution (answer), just not sure if this is the best approach